# Valid CSS structure using SCSS

Tags: css, sass, styles, scss-mixins

I would like to know if the below `SCSS` code sample is valid. This code is working fine as expected but would like to get more insight into this structure.

There are two inline elements with class name `setting-value` and `setting-name`, we need some extra margin in the right of `setting-value`.

Below is the code I have written:

**CASE 1**

```
.setting-value,
.setting-name {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  &.setting-value {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}
```

This will add an extra 10px left margin for an element with class setting-value. I can write this as below also:

**CASE 2**

```
.setting-value,
.setting-name {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}  
.setting-value {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Would like to know which is the correct structure to follow. Or what should be the best practices?

Comment: The first one generates a redundantly wordy `.setting-value.setting-value` rule, and a probably irrelevant `.setting-name.setting-value` rule. I'd definitely use the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
[class^="setting-"] {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

[class="setting-name"] {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

- This works only when class has only "setting-SOMETHING" value.
  For example, it works for `<div class="setting-value">` but not for `<div class="header setting-value">` since class needs to start with `setting-`.

Comment: Thanks, I never know that I can write CSS like this. Thanks.